# How do I make this jQuery mobile navigation script trigger only on small screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu, navigation

My jQuery is not very good - I'm trying to learn by piecing together bits of existing scripts but not having very much luck. I'm trying to get a menu on a Wordpress website to act as a normal horizontal navigation bar on large screen sizes and to become a jQuery dropdown on widths below 980px - I've got the dropdown working but can't figure out how to get it to work *only* on small screen sizes.

The code that works is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#mmenu").hide();
    $(".mtoggle").click(function() {
        $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

But obviously it hides the horizontal navigation on large screen sizes too.

I've tried

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($(window).width() < 979) {
    $("#mmenu").hide();
    $(".mtoggle").click(function() {
        $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

but it seems to break the code completely and make it entirely non-functional and I can't figure out why.

The website in question is http://host26.qnop.net/~fpsl/ if seeing the menu in context would be helpful.

Any advice would be very much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: You seem to have a syntax error on your site.  There are one too many closing brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you reindent the code you can see the problem... the if closes before the click handler function

here the corrected code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if($(window).width() < 979) {
    $("#mmenu").hide();
    $(".mtoggle").click(function() {
      $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i tend to do

```
body:before{content:".";display:none;} (for desktop)
body:before{content:"..";display:none;} (for tablet)
body:before{content:"...";display:none;} (for mobile)
```

and then just query that, as CSS and Javascript have slightly different sizes when measuring the window.